# cocos2d mac project alert window is below main window under full screen mode

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone, fullscreen

i am using cocos2d for my mac game. under full screen mode, the alert window is below the main window, which makes it not clickable. here is my code:

```
NSAlert* alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
alert.alertStyle = NSWarningAlertStyle;
[alert addButtonWithTitle:[Helper getLocalizedStringWithString:@"ok"]];
alert.messageText = [Helper getLocalizedStringWithString:@"you need to play through classic game and expert mode"];

switch ([alert runModal]) {
    case NSAlertFirstButtonReturn:
        break;

    default:
        break;
}    

[alert release];
```

I have tried to set the `[alert window]`s zOrder to MaxInteger, but still not showing on top.

Anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this NSAlert's method to present it:

```
- (void)beginSheetModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)window modalDelegate:(id)modalDelegate  
    didEndSelector:(SEL)alertDidEndSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
```

So you'll surely see it, since it's attached to the window.

**EDIT**

If you still want to have it as a separate panel, try this:

```
[[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
[alert runModal];
```

Comment: actually i still prefer the separated window approach. anyways the sheet modal is not bad

Comment: Maybe you can still run it with a separate panel and have it on the top.Try the code that I added in the edit.